# Common Lisp `format` implementation

Tags: format, common-lisp

Is there a particularly easy to read implementation of Common Lisp's `format`?

I've found [SBCL's version](https://github.com/sbcl/sbcl/blob/master/src/code/target-format.lisp), but since SBCL has a reputation for being a *performant* implementation of Common Lisp, I'm wondering if there's an implementation that focuses more on clarity and readability.

To be fair, SBCL's version isn't *too* hard to read, and I don't see a lot of optimizations, but if there's a *more* reader-friendly version I'd like to know about it!

Comment: https://github.com/robert-strandh/SICL/tree/master/Code/Format

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I don't see a lot of optimizations.

They are elsewhere. Just typing "format" in the REPL under [Emacs+Slime](https://common-lisp.net/project/slime/) and typing <kbd>M-.</kbd> brings up a buffer with the different locations associated with the symbol, including optimisations:

```
###/sbcl-1.3.7/src/code/cmacros.lisp
  (DEFINE-COMPILER-MACRO FORMAT)
###/sbcl-1.3.7/src/code/target-format.lisp
  (DEFUN FORMAT)
###/sbcl-1.3.7/src/compiler/srctran.lisp
  (:DEFTRANSFORM FORMAT (NULL (SB-INT:CONSTANT-ARG STRING) &REST STRING) "optimize")
  (:DEFTRANSFORM FORMAT (NULL FUNCTION &REST T) "optimize")
  (:DEFTRANSFORM FORMAT ((MEMBER T) FUNCTION &REST T) "optimize")
  (:DEFTRANSFORM FORMAT (STREAM FUNCTION &REST T) "optimize")
  (:DEFTRANSFORM FORMAT (T SIMPLE-STRING &REST T) "optimize")
  (:DEFOPTIMIZER FORMAT SB-C:DERIVE-TYPE)
  (:DEFOPTIMIZER FORMAT SB-C:OPTIMIZER)
###/sbcl-1.3.7/src/compiler/fndb.lisp
  (DECLAIM FORMAT SB-C:DEFKNOWN)
```

> [...] but if there's a more reader-friendly version I'd like to know about it!

You can read CLisp's [version](https://github.com/JoshCheek/clisp/blob/master/src/format.lisp) online on  the non-official github repository;
or Clozure CL's [implementation](https://github.com/Clozure/ccl/blob/003917cbbce90b7a7b5fa4bf90e9fe424e5637e9/lib/format.lisp). Look also at ABCL's [format.lisp](https://github.com/slyrus/abcl/blob/master/src/org/armedbear/lisp/format.lisp), as well as [ECL](https://gitlab.com/embeddable-common-lisp/ecl/blob/develop/src/lsp/format.lsp), etc. 
I can't provide a link to each Common Lisp implementation (see [this page](http://www.cliki.net/Common+Lisp+implementation) for a list).  From what I could see they all tend to have a lot of comments, but whether you find one more readable than another is up to you.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check them out!